# Which package causes the issue: yaml, icon or other?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

My RStudio project consists of 2 small files:

".Rprofile":

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Lithuanian")
```

and "index.Rmd":

```
--- 
title: "„R“"
---

# ...

`r icon::fa("external-link-alt")`
```

When I start RStudio project, the error message appears in the console:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Reader error: control characters are not allowed: #9C at 21
```

When I push "Knit" button, it results in an error:

```
processing file: index.Rmd

Quitting from lines 2-7 (index.Rmd) 
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Reader error: control characters are not allowed: #9C at 21
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Three components play here:

1. Lithuanian locale,
2. `„“` symbols and
3. icon::fa("external-link-alt").

If any of them is not present, the problem disappears.

**Question.** Which package is the primary cause of the issue: **yaml**, **icon** or the problem is elsewhere? And how should the problem be fixed so that all three components could be used?

Shortened version if the session info:

```
Session info -----------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.456)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257   
 tz       Europe/Helsinki             
 date     2018-08-20                  

Packages -----------------------------------
 package    * version date       source                            
 base       * 3.5.1   2018-07-02 local                             
 bookdown     0.7.17  2018-08-20 Github (rstudio/bookdown@4f9d73d)                   
 icon       * 0.1.0   2018-06-28 Github (ropenscilabs/icon@993fc64)             
 yaml         2.2.0   2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

**UPDATE.** The question was updated to reflect the problem more specifically:

- <s>`bookdown`</s>
- `yaml`
- `icon`
- other

Comment: Does the problem exist if you don't use bookdown? e.g. `output: html_document` instead.

Comment: If I leave only `title: "„R“"` in YAML header, the problem persists. Thus it's not `bookdown`. What would you suggest to try next?

Comment: I updated my question by removing `bookdown`

Comment: What encoding is the file saved as?

Comment: Files encoding is `UTF-8`. I tried `windows-1257` and the problem disappeared. Still it's strange that `UTF-8` fails.